If saying a Beracha over a worldly benefit is a logical mitzva, are non believers exempt? Are Chazal saying Hashem's existence is a svara?
According to  the Gemara (Brachot 35a), the halacha of saying a beracha before benefiting from the world is a svara; a halacha derived from logic:

סברא הוא: אסור לו לאדם שיהנה מן העולם הזה בלא ברכה
It is a logically derived halacha that it is is forbidden for man to
benefit from the world without a beracha

Simple question: if someone doesn't believe in God, is he patur (exempt) from saying berachot for worldly benefits? Note: non-Jews are exempt, even though this is logical.
If not, then is it because Chazal are actually saying that God's existence and ownership of the world is also a svara?
See this question and its answers for lots of good sources to look at regarding this.

What non believers are exempt from is Olam Habaah.

The conclusion is, that brachos are rabbinic and they obligated everyone jewish, so the question doesn't really start.

Also by they way believing God is also logical, as rav elchanan explains in beggining of kovetz mamarim regarding how non jews can be obligated to keep 7 laws, of they dont know god exists..

Why's all the bold? Svorah doesn't make it truly logical, it's only "logical" with implied assumptions. For example, that God YHWH exists and is the source of the food you eat. Non-YHWH believers might thank Jesus, Zeus, Vishnu, or any other god. Similarly, some do not believe in gods altogether, so for them, this "logic" applies to salespeople or farmers.

The phrase from Brachot 35a cited by the OP is from the beginning of the sixth perek of Brachot where the Gemara attempts to find a satisfactory scriptural source passuk (verse) from which to derive the obligation to make a bracha before eating. The Gemara is unable to do so for a variety of largely technical reasons.
The final conclusion of Brachot 35a is that no source passuk is needed. Instead, the conclusion is that the obligation is a sevarah, a logical inference because the entire world belongs to Hashem (see Tehillim 24:1 cited on Berachot 35a: לַה׳ הָאָרֶץ וּמְלוֹאָהּ – the earth and all it contains belongs to HaShem).
Therefore, it is logical that we must not derive benefit until we say a bracha and remind ourselves that the world is not ours.
This logic appears to be that a Scriptural verse is required to tell us something that we may otherwise not know. Gratitude to the Lord creator of the world is so obvious that no Scriptural source passuk is required.
In answer to the OP’s question:
"if someone doesn't believe in G-d, is he patur (exempt) from saying berachot for worldly benefits?"
my answer is that as a matter of halacha the obligation to say berachot is not dependent on the reason for brachot.
On the other hand, the non-believer, will not agree that he can be, as a matter of logic, subject to an obligation to thank a deity in whose existence he does not believe.

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

It's a very good answer. I don't want to accept it because I am not sure it has fully dealt with all the issues, and therefore I don't want to discourage further answers
